# Angular2- filter array of object from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of object. I tried array.filter but couldn't filter array from inside array.

Note: OPTIONGROUP array items were dynamic.

Array 1:

```
0:[{CATEGORYNAME:"Scrub Pants"
CATEGORY_ID:2
DESCRIPTION:null
IMAGE_URL_1:"http://www.pulseuniform.com/stylepic/AD-2513.jpg"
IMAGE_URL_2:"http://www.pulseuniform.com/stylepic/AD-2513.jpg"
IMAGE_URL_3:"http://www.pulseuniform.com/stylepic/AD-2513.jpg"
IMAGE_URL_4:"http://www.pulseuniform.com/stylepic/AD-2513.jpg"
NUM_OF_ORDERS:16
NUM_WISH_LIST:"100"
OPTIONGROUP:[
     {
      BRAND:'Adar Medical Uniforms'
      COLOR:'ASP:Asparagus'
      PRICE:'11.19'
      SIZE:'2XL'
      },
     {
      BRAND:'Adar Medical Uniforms'
      COLOR:'ASP:Asparagus'
      PRICE:'16.19'
      SIZE:'4XL'
      }],
PRICE: 175
PRODUCT_ID:17497
SALE_PRICE:11.19
SELLERNAME:"Adar Medical Uniforms"
SHORT_DESCRIPTION:"Adar Universal Unisex Natural-Rise Five Pocket Drawstring Tapered Leg Pants"
STYLECODE:"AD-2513"
STYLENAME:"Adar Universal Unisex Natural-Rise Five Pocket Drawstring Tapered Leg Pants"
THUMB_IMAGE_URL:"http://www.pulseuniform.com/stylepic/AD-2513.jpg"
VENDORNAME:"Adar"}]
```

How can I search array1 item from array2 inside optiongroup.
below is my array 2

Array 2 :

```
{COLOR:[{0:"ASP:Asparagus"},{1:"BRG:Burgundy"}],
SIZE:[{0:"M"}] }
```

Comment: arrays are delimited by []
What you call "array 2" is an object containing 2 arrays. Your "Array1" contains (one) object, itself containing another array. can you be more specific, give a precise example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: yeh actually array2 is an object containing array of color,size,brand etc

Comment: @Pac0 I need to filter array1 which have multiple objects (in this question I just show only 1 object) inside each object I have dynamic array of optiongroup . I need to search an item of second array in the objects of first array...Little bit confusing :P

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more efficient way to do it, but here's a fiddle with a working example using `Array.filter()` and multiple iterations.

https://jsfiddle.net/gmedyh6s/

I had to simplify your search params structure though

```
interface SearchParams = {
  SIZE: Array<string>,
  COLOR: Array<string>
};

const filterMyArray = function(array: Array<any>, searchParams: SearchParams): Array<any> {
  return array.filter( item => {

    // Parsing every search param
    return Object.keys(searchParams).map( param => {

        // Getting the array of params of the current item
        let itemOptions = item.OPTIONGROUP.map( option => option[param] );

        // Search param is contained in the considered array ?
        return searchParams[param].every( elem => itemOptions.indexOf(elem) > -1 );
    })

    // At this point we have an array of boolean, flattening it --> Must be true everywhere
    .reduce( (total,item) => {
            return total && item;
    }, true);

  });
}

const array: Array<any> = [ ... ];

const filtered = filterMyArray( array, {
  SIZE:['2XL'],
  COLOR:['ASP:Asparagus']
} );
```